# Firestore Timestamp properties are prefixed with underscore on admin SDK but not with client SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I load and stringify user data with the Firestore Admin SDK, timestamps have the following structure:

```
{
  "_seconds": 1566129600,
  "_nanoseconds": 0
}
```

When load and stringify the same data on the client, I get the following structure:

```
{
  "seconds": 1566129600,
  "nanoseconds": 0
}
```

Is there a good reason for this difference?

I am using JavaScript on the front end and a Node.js backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is the implementation details for Timestamp in either SDK.  You're not really supposed to depend on these details.  If you want to save and load a Timestamp object from JSON, you should read the time components using its documented public accessors for both seconds and nanoseconds.  Then, to reconstitute the Timestamp, pass those values into its constructor.

If the Timestamp object had a toJSON function, you could call that to get the object to serialize as JSON.  But it doesn't, and you can't just stringify the main object itself.  You could [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for that.

Comment: "You're not really supposed to depend on these details."
I really wish I wouldn't have to, I truly do.

I pre-load the collection on server. 
I order collection based on the timestamp.

All that is fine.

However, if I want to do pagination based on the `timestamp` property (because I cannot pass the whole `DocumentSnapshot` from server to client in pre-load), I need to convert Timestamp into a an object `{ seconds, nanoseconds }` to pre-load and then back when querying with cursor. My converter works for both SDK's, so I need to check for both underscore and non-underscore keys (?)

Comment: For anyone else who is having similar problems; I solved mine by converting `Timestamp` `toMillis()`, passing it from server to client and then recreating it using `fromMillis()`!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new Timestamp class:

```
class Timestamp {
    constructor(seconds,nanoseconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds
        this.nanoseconds = nanoseconds
    }
}
```

then call it:

```
const newCustomTimestamp = new Timestamp(_dobSeconds, _nanoSeconds);
```

and then overwrite your current Timestamp with the one we created and Swift will decode the keys correctly so you can use it on your client.